# Azure Devops Server Domain is not seen

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, user-permissions, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I use Azure Devops Server 2019 and want add user in Group Membership. We have trusted domain that is seen in server account groups, but when I want add user in azure devops administration console this domain is not seen. Why it is not seen and how can I connect user from trusted domain to azure devops server?

Answer (score 0):

To connect user from trusted domain to azure devops server:

We need to defined a DNS mapping for the server for eg: (Domain A)

Reference:
https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/Switches_Emulators_v2_2_015/help/nk_configuring_ip_information22.html

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-servicenow-platform/page/product/mid-server/task/t_MapIPAddressToDNSName.html